# Analytic solution at an irregular singular point of linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is easy to construct examples of linear ODEs with a regular singular point $z_0$ and a regular at $z_0$ solution. For instance, if one of the characteristic exponents at $z_0$ is a nonnegative integer, say $s$, then by the method of Frobenius we would have a solution of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k (z-z_0)^{s+k},$$ which is clearly analytic at $z_0$.

Is this situation possible (analytic, a not identically zero solution) also in the case of an equation with an irregular singular point?